# Java handling large numbers very strangely

Tags: java

I've been working on a program for a class that uses mass and diameter to calculate a planet's gravity according to the equation g = (G*m)/0.5d^2. I keep getting one digit values only as opposed a mix of one and two digit values. For example: For earth I got 9.8 m/s^2, but for Jupiter (supposed to be 24.9) I got (2.49). This is what I've written thusfar.

```
    public class PlanetGravity {

    public static double fromScientificToDouble(String scientific) {
        double output = Double.parseDouble(scientific.substring(0, scientific.indexOf("e")));
        output *= Math.pow(10, Integer.parseInt(scientific.substring(scientific.indexOf("e") + 1)));
        return output;
    }

    public static double calculateGravity(double d, String m) {
        double output = (fromScientificToDouble("6.67e-11") * fromScientificToDouble(m));
        System.out.println(output);
        output = output / (Math.pow(0.0005 * d, 2));
        System.out.println(output);
        output = Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(output).substring(0, Double.toString(output).indexOf(".") + 3));
        return output;
    }

    public static void printPlanet(String name, String diameter, String mass, String g) {
        System.out.println("  " + name + "\t\t" + diameter + "\t\t" + mass + "\t" + g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("  \t\t\t     Planetary Data");
        System.out.println("  Planet\t\tDiameter (km)\tMass (kg)\tg (m/s^2)");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printPlanet("Mercury", "4880", "3.30e23 ", Double.toString(calculateGravity(4880.0, "3.30e23")));
        printPlanet("Venus ", "12103.6", "4.869e24", Double.toString(calculateGravity(12103.6, "4.869e24")));
        printPlanet("Earth ", "12756.3", "5.972e24", Double.toString(calculateGravity(12756.3, "5.972e24")));
        printPlanet("Mars  ", "6794", "6.4219e23", Double.toString(calculateGravity(6794, "6.4219e23")));
        printPlanet("Jupiter", "142984", "1.900e27", Double.toString(calculateGravity(142984, "1.900e27")));
        printPlanet("Saturn", "120536", "5.68e26 ", Double.toString(calculateGravity(120536, "5.68e26")));
        printPlanet("Uranus", "51118", "8.683e25", Double.toString(calculateGravity(51118, "8.683e25")));
        printPlanet("Neptune", "49532", "1.0247e26", Double.toString(calculateGravity(49532, "1.0247e26")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the program in debugging mode to follow it line by line?  That should show you where the error actually occurs and why.  Do you have unit tests for your methods to verify that they do what you think they should be doing?

Comment: You are doing unit conversion wrongly. The diameters are in km, but G is in m^3/kg/s^2. You need to multiply `d` by 500, not 0.0005 as you did here.

Comment: Changed to 500 and it works! I must have looked over that line a thousand times and my brain still spaced that kilometers are bigger than meters

Comment: also, you can convert the 'e' directly, no need for all the substring stuffs. i.e. double num2 = Double.parseDouble( "3.30e23");

Answer (score 1):

you can simplify your codes by converting from Double to string directly, also using printf allows you to format your string (for example to 3 decimal places).

```
 public class PlanetGravity {

    public static double fromScientificToDouble(String scientific) {
        //you can convert "3.30e23" directly
        return Double.parseDouble(scientific);
    }


    public static void printPlanet(String name, String diameter, String mass, double g) {
        //using printf allows you more control over the formatting like set decimal places and alignment your strings. 
       System.out.printf("%10s  %15s  %12s   %8.3f \n", name, diameter, mass, g);
        // System.out.println("  " + name + "\t\t" + diameter + "\t\t" + mass + "\t" + g);        } 

    public static double calculateGravity(double d, String m) {
        double output = (fromScientificToDouble("6.67e-11") * fromScientificToDouble(m));
        output = output / (Math.pow(500 * d, 2));
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        System.out.println("  \t\t\t     Planetary Data");
        System.out.println("  Planet\t\tDiameter (km)\tMass (kg)\tg (m/s^2)");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printPlanet("Mercury", "4880", "3.30e23", calculateGravity(4880.0, "3.30e23"));
        printPlanet("Venus", "12103.6", "4.869e24", calculateGravity(12103.6, "4.869e24"));
        printPlanet("Earth", "12756.3", "5.972e24", calculateGravity(12756.3, "5.972e24"));
        printPlanet("Mars", "6794", "6.4219e23", calculateGravity(6794, "6.4219e23"));
        printPlanet("Jupiter", "142984", "1.900e27", calculateGravity(142984, "1.900e27"));
        printPlanet("Saturn", "120536", "5.68e26", calculateGravity(120536, "5.68e26"));
        printPlanet("Uranus", "51118", "8.683e25", calculateGravity(51118, "8.683e25"));
        printPlanet("Neptune", "49532", "1.0247e26", calculateGravity(49532, "1.0247e26"));

         

    }

}
```

your output will be something along the following

[image]